# Filling an array with pictureboxes

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of picture boxes created by:

```
PictureBox[] places = new PictureBox[100];
```

I need to fill it with some picture boxes I have in my form. Is there any way to programmatically fill out the array or will I need to use:

```
places[0] = pictureBox1;
...
```

Comment: I'm using C# in visual studio 2013 with the visual form editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my first example am making the assumption that you want to put your PictureBoxes into the array in the order they were created `pictureBox1 = places[0];` etc. The second example assigns the order they are placed in the array by using the Tag property as an index, this is the way that I normally use to add controls to an Array.

**First Method**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var places = new PictureBox[10]; // I used 10 as a test
    for (int i = 0; i < places.Length; i++)
    {
        // This does the work, it searches through the Control Collection to find
        // a PictureBox of the requested name. It is fragile in the fact the the
        // naming has to be exact.
        try
        {
            places[i] = (PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + (i + 1).ToString(), true)[0];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("pictureBox" + (i + 1).ToString() + " does not exist!");
        }

    }
}
```

**Second Method**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This example is using the Tag property as an index
    // keep in mind that the index will be one less than your 
    // total number of Pictureboxes also make sure that your 
    // array is sized correctly. 
    var places = new PictureBox[100]; 
    int index;
    foreach (var item in Controls )
    {
        if (item is PictureBox)
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)item;
            if (int.TryParse(pb.Tag.ToString(), out index))
            {
                places[index] = pb;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PictureBox[] places = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
```

This gets you every picture box defined in the control/Form

```
this refers to the Form
```

Comment: Is there any way to not select some picture boxes?

Comment: Yes, just put a where clause on the expression

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
var places = new PictureBox[100];
for (int i = 0; i < places.Length; i++)
{
  places[i] = this.MagicMethodToGetPictureBox();
}
```

Comment: How would you make `MagicMethodToGetPictureBox` return picture boxes sequentially?  He already has the picture boxes on the form.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood the OP's question; I thought that he wanted to know how to initialize arrays... Sorry about that!